# JavaScript acrobatics: How to declare an array, elements, and properties in one string

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

Given the following code:

```
eval('(mapping.' + binding.field + ' = eval("extVar") )');
```

where binding.field = `"LPP[0].price"` (a string) and
`extVar` is the same value of `"LPP[0].price"`

How could you program the statement above to end up with:

```
mapping.LPP[0].price = LPP[0].price;
```

when mapping.LPP isn't defined yet?  This code cycles through the Microsoft JQuery templates pulling variable names as strings from the tempaltes.  When we reference properties in arrays, it throws up based on this code.  It says that mapping.LPP[0] isn't defined.

Comment: `eval` within `eval` o_O

Comment: Whatever you are doing, you probably need to be shot for doing it. Anyway, +1 for something ev[ia]l but interesting.

Comment: What is `eval` within `eval` within `eval` within `eval`? ... Limbo :D

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, but it seems very likely that UR DOING IT WRONG!!!111

Comment: I'm pretty sure this summons Cthulhu.

Comment: @Vivin Paliath: funniest comment of the week :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!mapping.LPP) mapping.LPP = [];
mapping.LPP[0].price = LPP[0].price;
```

Comment: Very cool.  I went nuts with this answer on another question, which is also similar, but asks how to remove the eval statement from the code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159747/javascript-acrobatics-this-code-uses-eval-how-to-remove-it

Comment: Glad I could help :-)  And as an aside, Invader Zim is awesome.